# Python: Filtering large list by operations on list elements

Tags: python, filtering, processing-efficiency

I have a large list that I wish to filter. I want to do this by performing some operations on each element in the list and then delete
 any other matching elements in the list. The desired output is the shorter `ls`, with the matching post op elements removed. I can do it.. but it's really slow. 
 Do you have advice to speed things up?

An example list looks like:

```
ls = [1,2,3,......,10000000]
```

and the operations look like:

```
def performOps(x):
    a = x**2
    b = x**5
    c = x**7
    return a,b,c

for elem in ls:
    res = performOps(elem)
    for i in res:
        if i in ls[ls.index(elem)+1:]:
            ls.remove(elem)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work--it gives me `ValueError: 2 is not in list` at the `ls.index(elem)` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is slow because of multiple calls to `.index`.  Also, editing a list while you are also iterating over it is technically possible, but hard to debug.

Here's an approach where we first build a set of numbers that you want to delete, and then delete them with a single `filter` call.  The set of numbers is a set because, for large groups of numbers, it is much faster to test membership in a set than in a list:

```
# Make a set a numbers that we need to remove
toRemove = set()
for elem in ls:
    res = performOps(elem)
    for i in res:
        toRemove.add(i)
# Remove those numbers
ls = list(filter(lambda x: x not in toRemove, ls))
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot :)
But the only problem is that performOps returns a list, so I need to append to toRemove.

Comment: @user70434 This code will work if performOps returns a list, because the for loop works on any iterable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate()`.

```
# Iterate list along with index as 'i'
for elem in list(ls):
    res = performOps(elem)
    if i in ls:
        ls.remove(x)
```

Using `list(ls)` to iterate over the copy of the list preventing the indexing issue due to modification of list within the loop.

Comment: I was calling ls.index because I was using ls.remove. the list length is constantly changing so I didn't want to just use the i counter as the index position because the index of an element in ls may change from one iteration to the next.

Comment: Updated my answer. I am using `enumerate(list(ls))` to prevent the index of the list. `list(ls)` will create the copy of the `ls`. This way iteration will be on another list and index will be prevented. Also removed `if i in ls[i+1:]` condition.

Comment: Even more simplified the answer. We do not need enumerator. Is this is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert the list to a set? This ensures doubles are already removed.
Then extending the Moinuddin Quadri's answer

```
def filter(ls):
  final_list = set()
  for index, elem in enumerate(ls):
    final_list.add(elem)
    for item in performOps(elem):
       if item in ls:
         ls.remove(item)
  return final_list

ls = set([1,2,3.....10000])
ls = filter(ls)
```

Comment: Why are you converting `ls` to `set()`? It is possible that `ls` has duplicate values.

Comment: Are the duplicate values wanted? The original code looks to me like the duplicates are unwanted. If so we can save loop time by converting to a set and filtering duplicates before running the performOps method

Comment: This code has a bug: You need to check if the element is in the set before you try to remove it.  For perfomOps(1), it returns (1,1,1), and after you try to remove 1 the second time it will fail.

Comment: Thats what I get for coding at 11pm. @jgfооt thanks for the spot

Comment: @JaseRieger: I was doind that at 5 AM :D